# Get Similar rows count in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project in which a tutor can save its class timing. He can see his timing according to the days. I used the code

```
$qry = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from users left join time_slot on users.id=time_slot.u_id where users.id=' . $id);
echo '<table class="table_class" border="2">
                <tr>
                <th class="details">id</th>
                <th class="details">Date</th>
                <th class="details">start time</th>
                <th class="details">End Time</th>
                </tr>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['day'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['time_from'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['time_to'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

But It show  the multiple time if a tutor have multiple class in same day.
I want to show if he has 2 or more class on similar day(Monday) then all time slot show in a single row. Same this for all days of the week. How can I do it?

Comment: I have bounty it by mistake. Any one know how can I remove the bounty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function for this. Assuming your ddl is something like that

```
create table users(id bigint, name varchar(50));
create table time_slot(id bigint, u_id bigint, day datetime, time_from time, time_to time);
```

the sql would be as follows:

```
select u.id,u.name, ts.day, 
group_concat(ts.time_from, ' - ', ts.time_to ORDER BY ts.time_from, ts.time_to)
from users u left outer join time_slot ts on u.id = ts.u_id
group by u.id, u.name, ts.day
order by u.name, ts.day
```

See [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1b9a/4).

Comment: Hi @ozgur-bar, I don't know about the bounty. By mistake I have added bounty to this question. If you have any knowledge to remove it. Please help me

Comment: @Yogendra - This is not possible: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21529/ability-to-remove-the-bounty-and-get-reputation-back

Comment: Hi @Yogendra I've never asked a question on stackoverflow, so I have no idea how it's done..

Answer (score 0):

I have did with some temp values.
if you want in same way to impliment then it is usefull for you.

copy the code and check here http://phpfiddle.org/

```
$obj1['id']='1';
$obj1['name']='a1';
$obj1['day']='asdadh';
$obj1['time_from']='1';
$obj1['time_to']='1';

$obj2['id']='2';
$obj2['name']='a2';
$obj2['day']='asdad';
$obj2['time_from']='1';
$obj2['time_to']='1';

$obj3['id']='3';
$obj3['name']='a2';
$obj3['day']='asdad';
$obj3['time_from']='1';
$obj3['time_to']='1';


$arr = Array();
$arr[]=$obj1;
$arr[]=$obj2;
$arr[]=$obj3;


echo '<table class="table_class" border="2">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="details">id</th>';
echo '<th class="details">name</th>';
echo '<th class="details">day</th>';
echo '<th class="details">start time</th>';
echo '<th class="details">End Time</th>';
echo '</tr>';

foreach($arr as $row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['day'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['time_from'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['time_to'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>'; 

echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";

$dates=Array();
$count=0;
foreach($arr as $id=>$row){
    $val = $row['day'];
    $key = array_search($val,$dates);
    if(is_numeric($key)){
        $arr[$key]['day']=$dates[$key].','.$val;
        unset($arr[$id]);
    }else{
        $dates[$count]=$val;
    }
    $count++;
}

// new table 

echo '<table class="table_class" border="2">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="details">id</th>';
echo '<th class="details">name</th>';
echo '<th class="details">day</th>';
echo '<th class="details">start time</th>';
echo '<th class="details">End Time</th>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach($arr as $row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['day'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['time_from'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="details">' . $row['time_to'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```